# Using MPI with two RaspberryPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, mpich

I am trying to make a 'dual core' RaspberryPi for a project I am working on. I had followed this tutorial [by Simon Cox](http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~sjc/raspberrypi/pi_supercomputer_southampton_web.pdf). Unfortunately I could not get the two RasPi to talk to each other. (This was using Hydra as the process manager)

After looking more carefully at the MPICH installers guide, [which can be found here](http://www.mpich.org/documentation/guides/), I tried to use the -phrase  to pass the passphrase I had created. However I could not find it as part of the hydra commands. So I re-installed with smpd and after many compiling attempts. I configured with:

`/configure -prefix=/home/pi/mpich-install --with-pm=smpd --with-pmi=smpd`

I also had to install libbsl-dev to get the MD5 that smpd requires. I also exported the path that the commands mpiexec and mpicc are in. After setting the passphrase I copied the image to a second SD card and put it in a second RasPi. I then set up the passphrase using ssh-keygen.

I was able to run the cpi program on the master Pi and the slave Pi individually but when I tried to run multiple processes on both at the same time I got the error

`Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:`
``` MPIR_Init``_thread(392).................: ```
`MPID_Init(139)........................: channel initialization failed`
`MPIDI_CH3_Init(38)....................:`
`MPID_nem_init(196)....................:`
`MPIDI_CH3I_Seg_commit(366)............:`
`MPIU_SHMW_Hnd_deserialize(324)........:`
`MPIU_SHMW_Seg_open(863)...............:`
`MPIU_SHMW_Seg_create_attach_templ(637): open failed - No such file or directory`

Can someone please suggest how I can either fix this problem or get the RaspberryPis to communicate using MPICH?

Thanks
E.Lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem make sure your hosts don't have the same name! 
You can change it by following this tutorial http://raspi.tv/2012/how-to-change-the-name-of-your-raspberry-pi-new-hostname

Comment: Was that the answer to your question? If so, go ahead and accept your own answer here.